# Javascript for stopping browser from popup blocked

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am using this code for redirecting into new tab:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('http://example.com');</script>
```

but as i run this in Google Chrome it shows "POPUP BLOCKED" and it stills on the page.
So how can I stop google chrome from showing popup blocked by adding javascript.
I can stop this from my computer as there is an option in chrome "ALWAYS ALLOW" but if I publish it then every audience cannot do this.

Comment: `window.open` will be blocked by browser unless its a `user event`.

Comment: Popup blockers are there for a reason - and that reason appears to include you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "stop" Chrome from doing this, that is the whole point of a popup blocker.
And really, you should not try to create popups in the first place, people will hate you for it.

A new tab or window should only be opened as a result of a user action (and everything else is *rightfully* blocked), so the best way is probably to create a simple link (`<a>`) with `target="_blank"`.

But if I'm not mistaken, you actually are allowed to create popups in most browsers if the code in question is ran from the context of a `click` event handler (and a few others, e.g. `dblclick`, but not things like `mouseover`) if the event is a user event (as opposed to an event dispatched by a script).
So if a link is really not enough, try something like

```
myElement.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    window.open('http://example.com');
});
```

This will of course only work if the user clicks that element, but I can promise you, if they do not click it, they do not want to see a popup.

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2a4L3h4/2/).

Answer (score 0):

It is being blocked because it is a non-user-initiated popup.  There isn't a way to work around that that I know of, *nor should there be*.

Why do you want to open a popup, and what other choice could you make that still meets your goals?